# How to add a checkBox to each header in a grid?

Tags: grid, extjs4

I am running EXTJs4.11 and using a Grid. I need to be able to add a "checkBox" to each Grid column header. What I am attempting to do is offer the end user the ability to select a checkBox within a Grid header which will "SELECT" that column. By gathering all the "SELECTED" columns, I then want to be able to hide all other "NON-SELECTED" columns by using the RECONFIGURE method for extjs4 grids. I know Reconfigure will allow the user to redraw the grid with a different set of columns, using the same store if I use an undefined store parameter. I will be using ***reconfigure( undefined, iColumns)*** where iColumns is the array of the "SELECTED" columns. I am just not sure how to add a "checkBox" to each Grid header.

Comment: Does no one have an answer?

Comment: I think you need a custom Template (tpl) for this... Or to override the Ext.grid.header.Container component! There is no out of the box way, so you have to go your own way ;) Maybe you could place the dropdown menus elsewhere...

Comment: Any idea on how to do this - creating a custom header template or overrride for the header container?